# GA Event Tracking NOT Tracking in Realtime

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, universal-analytics

My code is using the new Universal GA code, with `ga(send` syntax, as follows: 
`<td id="newevent" onclick="ga('send', 'search-result', 'click', 'EVENTNAME');" ></td>`. 
I am using the Universal GA JS code in my  section.

`<html>`
`<head>`
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`
`<!-- Google Analytics -->`
`<script>`
`(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){`
`(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),`
`m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)`
`})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');`
`ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-A');`
`ga('send', 'pageview');`
`</script>`
`<!-- End Google Analytics -->`
`</head>`
`<body>`

`<a href="#" id="ec-search-result" onClick="ga('send','EVENTNAME','CATNAME','ACTION');">TEST</a>`
`</body>`
`</html>`

However, no event hits are registered in the GA Dashboard. Please advise.

Comment: Can you share the site?

Comment: Code is added to original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have made a small mistake in your cording. See you are sending the message, but with out saying  what is executing. You are missing “event” part in your code

New Code :

ga('send', **'event'**, 'search-result', 'click', 'EVENTNAME');